# Spring Boot ObjectMapper for @RequestBody annotation using Jackson Framework

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Hy guys.

I have some data, given by a jQuery DataTable, that I send to a Spring Controller using Ajax and the data elements. More specifically, the ajax function fragment is:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "../todaydatarecover.json",
                        type: "post",
                        data: dataToSend,
```

As explained me in another post here on Stack, I used (cause the presence of "data") the RequestBody annotation in my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/todaydatarecover.json")


@ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView todayInfoAndIdRecover(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody TodayData todayData) throws IOException
    {
```

and, always as explained me, I make a class that have the variables that are sent by ajax to controller; in method sign, you can se that her name is TodayData. This is the implementation:

```
public class TodayData 
{
    private long dateInBox;
    private String nameInBox;
    private String typeInBox;

<follow setters and getters>
```

Searching on the web, I found that an explicit setting for object mapper may be requested; so, I found for my configuration (Spring Boot and Jackson Framework, both on last version) this one:

```
@Bean
     public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
      jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
      return jsonConverter;
     }
```

that is putted in the `public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` file.

The data are passed to Controller as an Object:

```
$('#eventsdatageneral').on('click', '.btn.btn-info', function(event) 
            {
                var today_date = new Date().getTime(); 
                var dataToSend = new Object();
                dataToSend.dateInBox= today_date;
                dataToSend.nameInBox = host_name;
                dataToSend.typeInBox = type_name;
```

The problem is that when I click on the button that must enable sending, ***I got a 404 error.***

The object seems well formatted; on console, I got this:

[image: Object response]

And the parametr seems right:

[image: Object Parameters]

I got no errors on Java console;

So, what I don't understand is if i wrong the Object Mapper configuration or depends on what I implements on my controller, or other.

Comment: With PostMapping annotation, you don't need to specify @ResponseBody to method. Also you must return a POJO object instead of ModelAndView to write back in response to your REST service. Also you remove .json from PostMapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some changes in your code

1. You need to create JSON object as below in order to bind it with your Java POJO class `TodayData`:

   `$('#eventsdatageneral').on('click', '.btn.btn-info', function(event) 
           {
               var today_date = new Date().getTime(); 
               var dataToSend = {};
               dataToSend["dateInBox"] = today_date;
               dataToSend["nameInBox"] = host_name;
               dataToSend["typeInBox"] = type_name;`
2. While sending your ajax request you need to use JSON.stringify function which will convert your javascript object to JSON.

   `$.ajax({
                       url: "../todaydatarecover.json",
                       type: "post",
                       data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),`
3. Also as *alfcope* mentioned, `ModelAndView` and `@ResponseBody` shouldn't be used together, because when we use `@ResponseBody` on a method, we are saying that we do not want a view to be produced and the object will be returned as part of your response body.
4. Check the `url-pattern` in configurations you've done for this application, or correct the url which you are sending as `.json`.

Comment: Thnaks @RahulO. Your response makes my code working. I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@RequestBody` what means your controller is expecting a payload, so you need to serialise your JavaScript object using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) before sending it, otherwise it is going to be sent as url form enconded.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../todaydatarecover.json",
  type: "post",
  data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
  ...
});
```

Also, your request mapping looks wrong. You are returning a `ModelAndView` but using `@ResponseBody`. They should not be used together and it does not make sense return a `ModelAndView` to an ajax request.

I suggest you to remove extensions (`.json`) from your request mappings. It should be only:

```
@PostMapping(value="/todaydatarecover")
```